# Why stripe sends payment_intent.succeeded event to my webhook before callback from the client when the payment completes

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-api-php

Hi I'm using stripe custom flow to accept payments online in my site. After submit the payment to stripe and when stripe redirects to the return_url when a payment is successful I save the payment intent id with the order id in data base. I have configured webhook and something rare occurs Stripe sends the success event before redirects to the success url. Is that possible?

Comment: Why should that _not_ be possible? The user is on the stripe payment page, eventually sending data to their servers ... So why should their servers not send the notification to your webhook, and give feedback to the client (that it can redirect back to your site after successful payment now) at the same time?

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. I was wondering if i have configured something wrong, i would like to save in database the order id and the status send in webhook, but if stripe sends the webhook before i save order id, this would be a problem

Comment: You can pass additional meta data with your PaymentIntent object, and you will get that back in the webhook call. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#storing-information-in-metadata You could create an "incomplete" order on your end before the customer pays, or find some other data that allows you to associate this with a specific customer and/or order.

Comment: @CBroe Good idea, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rare yes, but not impossible. The webhook events sent from Stripe server to your server could arrive before your customer browser reaches your success page. For example if your customer phone just lost internet connection and recover after a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if i have configured something wrong, i would like to save in database the order id and the status send in webhook, but if stripe sends the webhook before i save order id, this would be a problem